# Escape characters in Perl

Tags: perl, escaping

A stupid question.

I'm trying to search and replace `"$option">$option_translated` with `$option>$option_translated`.

When I'm executing this command in unix terminal it's working fine.

```
sed -i 's/"$option">$option_translated/$option>$option_translated/g' filename.txt
```

But when I uses it in my Perl script it doesn't work

```
my $cmd = ("sed -i 's/"$option">$option_translated/$option>$option_translated/g' $filename");
qx{$cmd};
```

I think some characters need to be escaped here. Let me know which are those. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
my $cmd = ("sed -i 's/\"$option\">$option_translated/$option>$option_translated/g' $filename");
                here__^      __^
```

or use a different quoting operator instead of `"`, e.g.:

```
my $cmd = qq(sed -i 's/"$option">$option_translated/$option>$option_translated/g' $filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to call `sed` from Perl for that, use Perl's regex capabilities, just escape it using `\Q` `\E` or just, for e.g use (from my understanding you are trying to remove the `"`):

```
my $str = '"$option">$option_translated';

$str =~ s/"//g;
print $str;
```

Comment: Oh yes, will use this one, thanks :) but since in the question I used "sed" so I'll have to accept M42's answer.